# trend of ratio in kibana 4.0

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have documents under two daily indexes. Both have count field which is >=1.
I want to create a graph which shows trend of ratio of these two fields aggregated over time. 
Data will be sampled based on time duration selected in dashboard ex : for one day each sample would be be 10 min which will sum these two fields separately and calculate ratio and then show as one data point. So for 24 hours it would be 24*60 point in the graph.

How can I achieve same in Kibana 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

We tried something similar but turns out it is not possible in Kibana.
As of now you can not plot a calculated field based on two different fields in Kibana.

To workaround this, we implemented a plugin that modifies data before it is pumped to elastic search. So we carried out calculations in that plugin. Also, the plugin periodically pumps data to elastic search so kibana gets the latest values